What could cause a pod environment variable loaded from secret to not load latest version
I have a pod part of a statefulsel with this spec:
  containers:
    - name: XYZ
...
      env:
        - name: PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: MYSECRET
              key: password

Let's say at start the value of the secret "MYSECRET" was "123"
Later, the value of the secret "MYSECRET" has been updated to "456"
So far it is expected the env var isn't updated and the value within the pod is still "123".
Now I delete the pod, on recreation, the pod environment value for $PASSWORD is still "123".
What could cause this caching? The only solution we found so far to resolve is to drain the node then the new pod on the new node get the right value. Is there a setting to cache secret value on nodes?

Not sure if this is the one you are looking for but I faced the same issue, I did not deep dive into why it was happening but installed this https://github.com/stakater/Reloader in the namespace and every time a config map changes or a secret changes, this reloader will perform a rolling upgrade.

But why would the value stays the same after a pod deletion/recreation?

The issue is with the kubelet agent not syncing properly with the control plane. When deleting the pod it stays on the same node. The kubelet agent on the node for some reason isn't syncing properly with the control plane and doesn't have the updated secret value. The solution has been to restart kubelet: sudo systemctl restart kubelet then delete the pod.
